# Compass/SASS: extend imported bootstrap class

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807839/sass-extend-class-across-multiple-files) which I thought might work for me but unfortunately does not apply.
What I wish to accomplish is basically to assign bottstrap's `.input-sm` class to all `<input/>` and `<select/>` elements in my web app; but instead of searching the whole project and manually adding it, I thought I'd do this via css, like so:

```
/*app.scss*/
@import "bootstrap.min.css";

input, select {
    @extend .input-sm;
}
```

Compass complains it can't find the `.input-sm` selector; trying the suggestion posted in the aforementioned question:

```
/*app.scss*/
@import "bootstrap.min.css";

input, select {
    @extend %input-sm;
}
```

doesn't get me very far either, because compass still complains it can't find the `%input-sm` selector, this time.
Am I destined to go over all my pages and assign the `.input-sm` class to all my controls or is there an alternative I am overseeing? Cheers.

**EDIT**: I don't think this question should be marked as duplicate of [this other quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file) as user @cimmanon suggested, since I am experiencing no problem whatsoever in importing `bootstrap.min.css` to my `scss` file. The import works, what doesn't is the possibility of referencing classes from the imported file at compile-time.

**EDIT 2**: Ok, I realized that the other question, though I'm still convinced it is *not* a duplicate of this one, provides some insights as to how to achieve what I'm after: simply renaming bootstrap's css file to `scss` extension makes the `@extend` command work.

Comment: @cimmanon, I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question: I am perfectly able to import bootstrap's css, the only problem is that one of bootstrap's classes, namely `.input-sm`, isn't "seen" by compass at compile time, hence the error.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's being imported Sass style and not just being referenced CSS style?  You can't extend classes that are within .css files because Sass does not parse/interpret/compile them.

Comment: You're right, I re-edited my question providing info as to how I accomplished to do what I was after.